# How to set the color of VirtualStringTree header?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

The VirtualStringTree header has a 'Background' property but setting it to a different color does not change the color. I suspect the tree is rendered using Windows themes.

How can I set the color?

Comment: That property is used for header background, not for plates. And you would have to turn off themes for the control (exclude `toThemeAware` from `TreeOptions.PaintOptions`). What you're asking for sounds more like a task for custom drawing. What exactly do you want to paint (an image would be ideal) ?

Comment: Switching off ThemeAware is not an option because its not flat anymore. I just need a darker shade of gray as the header background color...

Comment: [Like this](http://i.imgur.com/xevOLcX.png) ? Note, that the background has no gradient on that picture. That gradient needs some extra work.

Comment: The whole background including the column headers is a single color. See the possibilities for db-grid header color customization in TSMDbGrid (by Mike Sholnik) for an example.

Comment: I think the best way forward is to make a request to the author to implement this (currently maintained by JAM Software).

Comment: It might be enough to move the drawing code into a sort of `DefaultDrawHeaderBackground` and `DefaultDrawHeaderPlate` methods. If you look closer to the code I've made, you'll see that if there would be such method, I could just call it and at the end call my `ColorBlend` procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use property `THeader.Background` but you'll have to exclude `toThemeAware` from `TreeOptions.PaintOptions`. That would turn off themes, as TLama already said in his comment above.

---

I recommend you to use the events `OnAdvancedHeaderDraw` and `OnHeaderDrawQueryElements`. `hoOwnerDraw` has to be included in `Header.Options` for them to take effect.

In `OnHeaderDrawQueryElements` you set `Elements` to (at least) `[hpeBackground]` and in `OnAdvancedHeaderDraw` you do the custom drawing.

See this example ([source](http://www.delphipraxis.net/664781-post5.html)):

```
procedure TfrmMain.MyVSTHeaderDrawQueryElements(Sender: TVTHeader;
  var PaintInfo: THeaderPaintInfo; var Elements: THeaderPaintElements);
begin
  Elements := [hpeBackground];
end;

procedure TfrmMain.MyVSTAdvancedHeaderDraw(Sender: TVTHeader;
  var PaintInfo: THeaderPaintInfo; const Elements: THeaderPaintElements);
begin
  if hpeBackground in Elements then
  begin
    PaintInfo.TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := clFuchsia; // <-- your color here
    if Assigned(PaintInfo.Column) then
      DrawFrameControl(PaintInfo.TargetCanvas.Handle, PaintInfo.PaintRectangle, DFC_BUTTON, DFCS_FLAT or DFCS_ADJUSTRECT); // <-- I think, that this keeps the style of the header background, but I'm not sure about that
    PaintInfo.TargetCanvas.FillRect(PaintInfo.PaintRectangle);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Better add `if not Assigned(PaintInfo.Column) then` statement to the query elements event. The `hpeBackground` element is used also for drawing plates. And in the drawing event just fill the rectangle.

Comment: @TLama What do you mean with "plates"?

Comment: Great answer! I'll accept it when the code is final.

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/TvrB4de.png). And do just [this](http://pastebin.com/nT9NiaLZ). That themed painting attempt is poor.

Comment: Maybe, OP should clarify what he meant with "background". I understood him as that he wants to color both, plates and unused background space. If I misunderstood him, then you are totally right.

Comment: I think that its well understood what 'header' means. The entire top row is considered a header.

Comment: Sure, but header has parts. The base parts are plates and background. You've said me that you want to have different background. Now we are talking about background and plates as well ? I'm confused :(

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just want the ability to set the header background color (the whole background including column headers with one single color). I am used to the functionality available in TSMDBGrid (Mike Sholnik).

Comment: [Nothing fancy](http://pastebin.com/59a7X4D1). Due to lack of missing default drawing method you need to *copy* (and maintain) the painting method from the source (the code is from VTV 6.1.0). All that just for calling one extra function (that blends the rectangle over the just painted element).

Comment: @TLama: Thanks for the effort put into this. It looks like I have to go this route.

Comment: @TLama: Your code looks very long. I think that its best that the authors implement the requested feature into the component, that way it will be most optimum, rather than all this custom draw events (VirtualStringTree1AdvancedHeaderDraw). So I will skip this code for now and just use the normal / default color.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TfrmDepositDefrayalSingly.vstItemsManuallyHeaderDrawQueryElements(Sender: TVTHeader;
  var PaintInfo: THeaderPaintInfo; var Elements: THeaderPaintElements);
begin
  Elements := [hpeBackground];
end;


procedure TfrmDepositDefrayalSingly.vstItemsManuallyAdvancedHeaderDraw(Sender: TVTHeader;
  var PaintInfo: THeaderPaintInfo; const Elements: THeaderPaintElements);
begin
  if hpeBackground in Elements then
  begin
    PaintInfo.TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := cGlobalVar.BasicColor;
    PaintInfo.TargetCanvas.FillRect(PaintInfo.PaintRectangle);

    if Assigned(PaintInfo.Column) then
    begin
      PaintInfo.TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := clGray;
      PaintInfo.TargetCanvas.FrameRect(PaintInfo.PaintRectangle);
    end;
  end;
end;
```