# TVirtualStringTree - How to draw on header columns without using OwnerDraw?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I would like to draw on the `TVirtualStringTree` header columns but I have a problem. I need the tree columns to use it's "default draw" and add my own graphics on it.

If I use `hoOwnerDraw` with `Header.Options` and use `OnHeaderDraw`, I need to completely draw the columns myself (which is no good).

There is the `OnAdvancedHeaderDraw` which seems to be what I hope for ([see example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32397413/937125)):

> Used when owner draw is enabled for the header and a column is set to
>   owner draw mode. But only if OnHeaderDrawQueryElements returns at
>   least one element to be drawn by the application.

If I use `OnAdvancedHeaderDraw` (I must also use `OnHeaderDrawQueryElements`) I get what I want, *but* I need to **substitute** at-least one element in the `OnHeaderDrawQueryElements` (i.e. `hpeBackground`/`hpeDropMark`/`hpeHeaderGlyph`/`hpeSortGlyph`/`hpeText`) and draw it myself in the `OnAdvancedHeaderDraw` event.

When for example I return the `hpeSortGlyph` element, returning `ShowSortGlyph := True` in the `var PaintInfo: THeaderPaintInfo` of the `OnAdvancedHeaderDraw` does not make any difference, and the sort glyph is not painted, which means I must paint it myself. Since there is no `DefaultDrawSortGlyph` I need to reinvent to weal, so to speak, and copy big parts of code from VT source just to paint the sort glyph :/

I use/need all the elements in the columns, I just want to **add** my own graphics on top of the default column graphics (a drop down arrow) without substituting one of them. How can I avoid this behavior? Is it possible to draw on top of the exists column without patching the source?

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: No, that is not possible at this time. But as a simple modification might be e.g. extending `THeaderPaintElements` by for example `hpeOverlay` and line `ActualElements := RequestedElements * [hpeHeaderGlyph, hpeSortGlyph, hpeDropMark, hpeText];` change to `ActualElements := RequestedElements * [hpeHeaderGlyph, hpeSortGlyph, hpeDropMark, hpeText, hpeOverlay];`. Then you would query just for the `hpeOverlay` element, all others would be painted by default and the `OnAdvancedHeaderDraw` event will get fired just for that new element.

Comment: @Victoria, *"No, that is not possible at this time"* -  I already came up with the same conclusion. I added a new event `OnAdvancedHeaderDrawEx` which does not depend on the `hoOwnerDraw` flag. But I really like your simple solution (Which I think should be added in next versions). Can you please post an answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: I only fail to understand why the `PaintInfo` is passed as `var` to the event if I can't change it.

Comment: I like Victoria's solution too and opened an issue for it: https://github.com/Virtual-TreeView/Virtual-TreeView/issues/722

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since VT 7.0 you can query and paint for the **hpeOverlay** header paint element.

---

For older versions:

There is no easy way to paint over the fully rendered header column at this time (VT 6.7.0). But a simple modification of the source code might be e.g. extending **THeaderPaintElements** flag set by for example **hpeOverlay**, and line:

```
ActualElements := RequestedElements * [hpeHeaderGlyph, hpeSortGlyph, hpeDropMark,
  hpeText];
```

change to:

```
ActualElements := RequestedElements * [hpeHeaderGlyph, hpeSortGlyph, hpeDropMark,
  hpeText, hpeOverlay];
```

Then you can query just for the **hpeOverlay** element in the **OnHeaderDrawQueryElements** event, all the elements will be painted by default and the **OnAdvancedHeaderDraw** event will be fired just for this new element.

The main contributor Joachim Marder filed an [**enhancement issue**](https://github.com/Virtual-TreeView/Virtual-TreeView/issues/722) to add this kind of extension, which has been commited to the repository, so the current version of VT supports the proposed enhancement.